# PowerBI DAX Comparing two measures

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals, daxstudio

I am having an issue and cannot figure it out, since I am still pretty new on DAX.
Currently, I am having a table in the database, where it stores the "Extracted" documents that have been automatically extracted value by the software. I also have the second step, during this process, called Validation - "VA02", the value can be manually changed or leave it as it came from "EX02".

I need to create a DAX measure that would return the distinct count of Document ID for the count of CALL_POINT = "VA02" that Values differ from the CALL_POINT = "EX02".

|  | DOCID | CALL_POINT | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 654474 | EX02 |  |
| 2 | 654474 | EX02 | 44.57 |
| 3 | 654474 | EX02 | 0.00 |
| 4 | 654474 | VA02 |  |
| 5 | 654474 | VA02 | 0.00 |
| 6 | 654474 | VA02 | 0.00 |

The first row of EX02 corresponds with the first row of VA02, etc. There is a difference in lines 2 and 5, which means the value was changed manually. So the expected result, in this case, should be 1.

|  | DOCID | CALL_POINT | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 654475 | EX02 | 0.00 |
| 2 | 654475 | VA02 | 0.00 |
| 3 | 654476 | EX02 | 10.00 |
| 4 | 654476 | VA02 | 15.00 |
| 5 | 654477 | EX02 | 95.73 |
| 6 | 654477 | VA02 | 95.00 |

In this example, the output should be 2. Since the value between EX02 and VA02 differs in DOCID 654476 and 654477.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to compare the sum of `VALUE`, for each `DOCID` for specific `CALL_POINT` values.

My solution is to create a measure `Check` that calculate the sum of `VALUE` where type is "EX02" and "VA02". Then, to compare these two sums and return error when they are different.

The measure. Please note that the table is named "TMP" below:

```
TMP[Check] =
VAR SumEX02 =
CALCULATE(
    SUM(TMP[VALUE]),
    TMP[CALL_POINT] = "EX02"
)
VAR SumVA02 = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(TMP[VALUE]),
    TMP[CALL_POINT] = "VA02"
)
VAR Result =
SumEX02 - SumVA02
RETURN
IF(
    NOT Result = 0,
    "Error",
    "Ok"
)
```

The, you can create a new table visualisation with columns :

- `DOCID`
- The new measure `Check`

Or run the following table expression:

```
NewTable =
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(
        TMP,
        TMP[DOCID]
    ),
    "Check",
    TMP[Check]
)
```